# Matrix table linked to Components in Angular

Tags: angular, matrix, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am looking to create a matrix table in Angular, based on some sql tables.
I have 3 tables and related components retrieving their data: Member, Issue, and Skill level (linked to the 2 others).
One member can have skills in different types of issues/domains with different skill levels (1 to 3), so I'd like a table like that, for example:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G37tb.png
So for the x-axis the list of the issues, the list of the members for the y-axis and the skill level as the main data.

Here is the code of the Issues Component, as an example, with my method to retrieve the issues :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {IssuesService} from './issues.service';
import {Issues} from './issues.interface';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-issues',
  templateUrl: './issues.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./issues.component.css']
})
export class IssuesComponent implements OnInit {

  issues: Issues[];

  constructor(private issuesService: IssuesService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.issuesService
      .getIssue()
      .subscribe((data: Issues[]) => {
        this.issues = data;
      });
  }}
```

How my array Issues[] looks like :

```
0: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 1, OnCall_Issue: "rugby"}
1: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 2, OnCall_Issue: "Archi"}
2: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 3, OnCall_Issue: "Node"}
3: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 4, OnCall_Issue: "JS"}
4: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 5, OnCall_Issue: "Java"}
5: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 6, OnCall_Issue: "tennis"}
6: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 9, OnCall_Issue: "football"}
7: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 10, OnCall_Issue: "Mathématiques"}
8: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 11, OnCall_Issue: "Barbecue"}
9: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 12, OnCall_Issue: "Flute"}
10: {Id_OnCall_Issue: 13, OnCall_Issue: "Problème 1"}
length: 11
```

I managed to create a normal table for each component, but I really want a matrix table for all of them. I looked at some tutorials but couldn't find a proper solution.

I found this code, which could be what I need but I don't know how to adapt it to my data. I don't see how to connect my Components to the scope of ng-repeat.

```
 <div id="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th ng-repeat="year in years">{{year}}</th> //Could be replaced with my "issues"
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
        <th>{{name}}</th> //Could be replaced with my "members"
        <td ng-repeat="year in years">{{tallies[year][name] || 0}}</td> //Could by replaced with my "skill level"
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thank you a lot in advance :)

Comment: Please post the structure of `this.issues` array. Does it contain all the data required to display the table? Better would be to do a `console.log(data)` inside the subscription and posting it in the question.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelD, I edited my question to post the Issues array structure